# custom manager is returning all the objects django.11 postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-managers

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        queryset = super(CustomManager, self).get_query_set()
        return queryset.filter(
            models.Q(expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today()) |
            models.Q(
                expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=40),
                is_invoice_emailed=True
            )
        )

class Subscription(models.Model):
      ....
      objects = CustomManager()
      default = models.Manager()
```

when I access `Subscription.objects.all()` it's returning all the records in db without filtering. but, If I use below query

```
queryset = Subscription.objects.all()
queryset.filter(
                models.Q(expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today()) |
                models.Q(
                    expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=40),
                    is_invoice_emailed=True
                )
            )
```

It is returning filtered results. Why?

I'm using django==1.11.11, python2.7 and db Postgresql

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the second manager is not assigned to `default` but rather another name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_query_set()` method should be typed like `get_queryset()`

You may also use QuerySet directly instead of Manager:

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def get_result(self):
        return self.filter(
            models.Q(expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today()) |
            models.Q(
                expiration_date__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=40),
                is_invoice_emailed=True
            )
        )

class Subscription(models.Model):

    ...

    objects = CustomQuerySet().as_manager()
```

The pros of above is that you no longer have to provide Manager class.

From now you can use it like: `Subscription.objects.get_result()`

Answer (score 0):

The method all() on a manager just delegates to get_queryset(), and it is design to return all the objects on dB.
If you would use a filter method like filter() or exclude(), you would already have the QuerySet, and it return certain object which matches the condition of filter.
You can learn about queryset on 
[django queryset documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)